# Use variable for property name in JavaScript literal?

Tags: javascript

I know we can create new properties in Javascript objects during runtime but could that property be assigned a value too? For example.

```
var value = "New value";

var table = new Object();

var newValue = table[value];
```

Now, I know that value table has a new property called "value". but does that "value key contains the information as " New Value". So, does that mean now table object is like following:

```
table = {
value:"New Value";
}
```

Comment: btw, object literal notation `{}` is way nicer than `new Object()` in almost any possible way.

Comment: Also, a semicolon (`;`) inside an object literal `{ ... }` is invalid. Use commas (`,`) to separate properties INSIDE object literals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing accessing with assigning.

```
// Assigns a variable named 'value' with a value of 'New Value'.
var value = "New value";
// Creates a variable named 'table' as a blank Object.
var table = new Object(); // Alternatively - table = {};
// Attempts to access "New Value" from object "table" which returns undefined.
var newValue = table[value];
```

If you want to assign properties to an object you do so like this:

```
// Assumes table is still an object.
table['key'] = 'value';

// Note that I almost _always_ opt for the variable['key'] notation over
// the variable.key notation because it allows you to use keys
// that would otherwise not be valid as identifiers.
table['Some Key'] = 'Some Value'; // This works.
table.Some Key = 'Some Value'; // This does not.
```

Later, when you want to retrieve that value and store it in a new variable, that's when you do this:

```
var newVariable = table['key'];
```

Hopefully that clarifies some.  Please let me know if I can expand on any part of it.

Answer (score 3):

no.  your statement

`var newValue = table[value];`

is not setting anything, and since at the time when you created `table` you didn't assign any property, `newValue` will be `undefined`.

If you have a `value` variable that is assigned a value, and you want to assign that value to table under the key `value`, you want to do

`table['value'] = value;`

or alternatively

`table.value = value`

Answer (score 1):

Erm, no, I don't think you've got it quite right.

All that does is assign `undefined` to `newValue`, because you're trying to access `table`'s "`New Value`" property, which doesn't exist.

What I think you're trying to do is this:

```
var value = "New value";
var table = {};
table.value = value;
```